# Selenium get text from tooltip

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I am writing some automation tests for a website and i'm trying to verify the contents of a tooltip. In this instance I am testing with Google Chrome. The code is written in C#.

I have the xpath correct for the element (span) which when hovered over pops up the tooltip but the code I have written never seems to popup the tooltip. If I mouse over manually it does.

The code is as follows:

```
    // This xpath has been verified using the google chrome extension and there is one match. This xpath matches the element that I want to hover over in order for the tooltip to appear.
    var xPathString = $"//*[text()='{dataSourceName}']/following::div[contains(@class,'somepath')]";

    var row = tblDataSources.FindElement(By.XPath(xPathString));
    TimeSpan WaitSeconds = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 10);
    Thread.Sleep(WaitSeconds);

    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    builder.MoveToElement(row).Build().Perform();

    // This contains "TestCollector1 (+3)"
    var actualText = row.GetText();
```

When running the test the popup never appears and the actualText variable is set to the span text value rather than the tooltip value that should appear when hovering over. This is the issue.

The html is as follows:

```
<div class="col-sm-2 hidden-xs somepath"><span data-original-title="" title="">TestCollector1 (+3)</span></div>
```

This is how the popup looks when it appears if I hover manually:
[image]

This is the span and the label as it looks in the webpage:

[image]

Does anybody have any ideas why as the code looks correct, as per any Google searches I've done.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML

Comment: Incase _when you hover over the pop up the tooltip never seems to popout_ essentially means that there is something wrong in the _xpath_ or a _sync_ issue. Update the question with the relevant _HTML_

Comment: Thank you. I have posted the relevant HTML but I will do some more digging regarding the sync issue. The XPath is correct, as when I do a test it finds the exact match. This is why the value for actualText contains: "TestCollector1 (+3)". However it doesn't cause the popup to appear. To clarify I am interested in obtaining the the popup text which is injected into the DOM on hover over the span (See above HTML output)..